How to extract a component from dynamically loaded angular remote module
How to extract the Component from module federation remote module
At present I am having the below code
Remote code:
exposes: {
        './TodoModule': './src/todo/todo.module.ts',
        './TodoComponent': './src/todo/todo.component.ts'
    },

Shell Code:
const {TodoComponent} = await loadRemoteModule({
  type: 'module',
  remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4300/remoteEntry.js',
  exposedModule: './TodoComponent',
});
this.ref.createComponent(TodoComponent);

So its working as expected.
Now I want to do the same without exposing the component
Remote Code:
exposes: {
'./TodoModule': './src/todo/todo.module.ts'
},
Shell Code:
const {TodoModule} = await loadRemoteModule({
  type: 'module',
  remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4300/remoteEntry.js',
  exposedModule: './TodoModule',
});

I need to extract a particular component from it and add it in the below code
this.ref.createComponent(TodoComponent);

Do we have any way to extract the Component from the above Module?

Could you please provide further details for the use case and explain why you don't want to expose the component from the remote MFE?

Because I have lot of components are there. Also when we load the application module, it will bootstrap all the required configs. For eg: Routing, NgRx  etc.
